# call a jaggery Array inside javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, jaggery-js

I have a jag file which will contain an array. Inside that jag file I also have a javascript function, what I want to do is to call the array inside that javascript

```
<%
var types = jsonObj.component.type;
var typeId = new Array();
var typeRole = new Array();
for(var i=0;i<jsonObj.component.type.length;i++) {
    typeId[i] =types[i].id;
    typeRole[i] =types[i].roles;
}
log.info("----------"+typeId[0]+ typeRole[0]);
%>
```

in the same file ,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function generateResponse() {

}
</script>
```

I want to read the array typeid inside the generateResponse function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first snippet is a server side template, which is going to be executed before `generateResponse` is loaded by the user's browser. There are a few ways to get around this but the easiest would be to insert a script tag with a variable equal to your array, and then use that variable in your script below:

```
<%
var types = jsonObj.component.type;
var typeId = new Array();
var typeRole = new Array();
for(var i=0;i<jsonObj.component.type.length;i++) {
    typeId[i] =types[i].id;
    typeRole[i] =types[i].roles;
}
log.info("----------"+typeId[0]+ typeRole[0]);
%>

<script> var typeId = <%= typeId %>;</script>
```

The variable `typeId` should now be accessible in your `generateResponse` function.

I would also suggest transforming your data *before* you hit the template, but that's just me.

Comment: Thanks :)  it works. Is there a good tutorial other than the jaggery.org which I can follow?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not. I hadn't heard of jaggery before your question :) I'm not sure how far you are into your project, but it may be useful to switch to a more proven framework like [hapi.js](http://hapijs.com/) or [express](http://expressjs.com/) both of which have extensive documentation and support.

Comment: There is [an example Jaggery application](https://github.com/ruchiraw/wso2-samples-store) to demonstrate the features of caramel framework. Hope it'll be help for you to learn jaggery.